# Edit a field value of a BSON document using Mongo C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I was attempted to update a few field values of a BSON document using the Mongo C++ driver, but it seems like my implementation using `$set` does not work properly.

```
mongo::BSONObj update(mongo::BSONObjBuilder b, mongo::BSONObj bson, int 
value)
{
    b.appendElements(BSON("$set" << bson));
    b.appendElements(BSON("$set" << BSON("modified" << mongo::DATENOW));
    b.appendElements(BSON("$set" << BSON("category" << value));
    mongo::BSONObj o = b.obj();

    return o;
}
```

Comment: Two things here. 1) You are using the legacy C++ driver, which has been EOL for more than a year. 2) The `$set` operator is about mutating BSON held on a remote server. It doesn't mutate the local object in your process.

Comment: Yes the version that I am using C++ driver version released in March, 2016. mongo --version output 2.6.12. Yes I was trying to locally mutate a BSON document. I'm surprise that it doesn't work locally. Do you have any reference where I could read more on `$set`

Comment: The `$set` syntax is part of the database's update language. It is what you send to a remote server to execute an update operation against the stored documents. It is not a way of expressing local mutations. Also, MongoDB 2.6 has been EOL for a very long time. I cannot recommend you use it in production.